# EXE without (or encrypted) RCDATA?

Tags: delphi, exe

I'm compiling my application with Delphi 2010. My problem (it may not be a problem for anybody else) is that when you open that EXE with any resource editor you can see RCDATA which holds forms data. I don't like an idea of my program being "exposed" so I want to ask you is there any trick to remove that information from EXE or encrypt it that nobody (at least from resource editor) can see it?

Answer (score 2):

You may create your forms fully via source. 
opposite: you can't use the form designer.

with [gexperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) you can convert existing forms to source.

encrypting and compressing is not a solution. when the app can load the resources a engineer can it do, too.

Comment: When you know it is a Delphi application, running the app in a debugger can yield full form structures at runtime quite easily, even if you generate the form/frame itself by code. This is equivalent in complexity to hooking the RCDATA stream loading and inserting some decryption code there.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a DFM compressor that works inside of the Delphi IDE to compress DFMs at compile time.  It then decompresses them on the fly at runtime.

I sell it for $15 US and it comes with src.

It currently works with D7, D2006, D2007 and D2009.  I don't own D2010 but I have recently gotten XE and I will be upgrading it and making it available for XE as well in the near future.  If someone makes a request for XE, or even D2010 compatibility, I'll work to make that happen sooner.

It's called the DeForM System and can be found [here](http://www.mills-enterprise.ca).

I use it for a number of my personal projects.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify VCL source code to teach form loader to take resources elsewhere. Also, compilation would require post-build step or stripping resources from the compiled EXE and moving them to a separate encrypted file (for example). All of this is manual work, I never heard of any automation for described tasks.

One thing you could do IF your forms are finalized (i.e. they won't be modified further) is take GExperts and use their Component To Code expert to create forms and their contents in runtime. But modification of such forms will require changes in code.

Answer (score 0):

It actually just holds published property of the components you drop on your forms and the form itself (actually the content of DFM file for each form), not any source code. So even if somebody extracts that data, they can at most produce a form visually looking the same as your form, but none of the codes you wrote for the form.

One way to hide such data from resource editors is to build all the components you use in your form at runtime, not using the form designer. This way, the DFM resource will not contain their data. As far as I remember, there are tools which are able to receive a DFM file as input, and generate runtime code for component creations automatically (e.g. GExpert), so that you could copy\paste the code in your form's OnCreate event-handler.

Another option is to use an EXE compressor. A compressor will compress your EXE file so the content of the file will be changed and not usable until being decompressed. Tools like [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) can compress your EXE file and decompress it on the fly when you execute the EXE. Take note that using known compressors like UPX has the drawback that many cracking tools or crackers can detect them and automatically decompress the EXE before processing it. So if you need more security, you'd better go for custom compressors.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but [Citadel for Delphi](http://www.billeniumsoft.com/ctd/) does automatic compression and encryption of DFM resources in your EXE.  It doesn't look like they've updated past Delphi 2009 yet, but it's exactly what you're looking for.